# Formulas - Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I need the cells from Aug to Dec to be formatted automatically based on the "plan numbers" if actual numbers are higher (green); if lower (red)- I'm trying to set it up so when data comes (based on the months) the cells will update automatically to green or red. When I add the formula to make the cells red based on the data they turn red before I add the data; they need to remain blank.

I need to find or add an exception to the formula so that ONLY when the numbers are there and if they fall below the "plan" the cells turn red, right now it's assuming the numbers are 0 because there's no data so blank cells turn red. What's the right formula to use? This is "sheet1" - Data comes from "sheet2" - RESOLVED

I'm using

```
=(H5-H4)<0
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward yet I can't find the right formula - What is the exception to the formula so the blank cells don't turn red, if I run or extend the rule all the way to the month of December it turns the cells red. I've used different variations of IF. Does anybody know? Does this make sense?

Comment: Have you tried adding another formula (=isblank(act_cell)) and format that to white. Then arrange that as your first formula.

Comment: =Isblank worked to keep the cells white/blank when there's no data. I have both formulas shown here running through all months, the rule that will show green cells works, the rule for the red cell doesn't, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to AND (NOT(ISBLANK) with rest of the condition to work it correctly. See the below screenshot.

[image]

There are only two rules

Rule 1 -

[image]

Rule 2-

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, but if there's no data yet for the upcoming months, how do I keep those cells blank, when I run the rule it changes all the empty cells to red (0) I assume because there's no data. Maybe there isn't a way to do that? I attached another screenshot above, I'm setting it up so when they run the reports and they input the numbers, the cells will update automatically to green or red, depending on what those numbers are. Hopefully this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: If there's plan data but no actual data and the cell is truly blank (not even 0 or any other formula) then it should not turn red. I created rule for just one cell D4 and used Format painter to apply it all all. Can you show the full formula? It should apply to one cell like $D$4. Also I see 0 entered in Jul-Dec cells. Then it's not blank.

Comment: This worked. Thank you